# Cuadriga que remata uno de los torreones del edificio

Tags: significado-en-contexto

¿Qué significa "remata" en "[cuadriga que remata uno de los torreones del edificio](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edificio_del_Banco_de_Bilbao_%28Madrid%29#/media/Archivo:Madrid_-_Edificio_del_Banco_de_Bilbao_2.jpg)"? No creo que signifique "[dar fin o remate a algo](https://dle.rae.es/rematar) (torreón) ... ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

*Cuadriga que remata uno de los torreones del edificio, obra de Higinio Basterra*.

En Arquitectura cuando se habla de "**remate**" se refiere a **todas aquellas partes de la construcción que embellecen y decoran en la cima de la misma.** En este caso, si no estas familiarizado con estos términos o simplemente te resulta confuso, siempre puedes sustituir la palabra "rematar" con otras que vienen a decir lo mismo en este ámbito, como "acabar, concluir, terminar".

***3. m. Elemento que en las construcciones se sobrepone para coronarlos o adornar su parte superior***.

Preferible buscar "**Remate**" en lugar de "Rematar", que es el enlace que aparece indicado en la pregunta.

**Remate**

https://dle.rae.es/remate?m=form

Así podríamos decir;

- "*Cuadriga que concluye uno de los torreones del edificio, obra de Higinio Basterra*".
- "*Cuadriga con que acaba (la cima de) uno de los torreones del edificio, obra de Higinio Basterra*".

Son también remates en edificios los pináculos, los merlones, los cimácios, las almenas...

*No confundir este "**remate**" con aquel otro "remate" que se utiliza en las subastas que se realizan con determinados objetos que se venden o donan en beneficio de alguien.*

Comment: ,¡Muchísimas gracias por hacerme entender el significado de "rematar" en este contexto!

Comment: ! Gracias a ti ¡ Feliz entrada de año.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias, Diego! ¡Felices fiestas a Usted también!